# radioButton values changing from numeric to character in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have the code shown below. I load example.RData where I have a model created before (mdl_example). The model just depends on the variable sex. The thing is I get the following message when I run the app:

variable 'sex' was fitted with type "numeric" but type "character" was supplied

The thing is it seems that when I use the predict function the pred_data dataframe has "Male" or "Female" as the value. However, if I don't use the predict function and just use:

paste("The result is", pred_data[1,1]) or paste("The result is", input$sex)

the output is correct and it appears a 1 or a 0 depending on where the radioButton is selected. The problem is when I use the predict function it seems it is not. It makes no sense for me.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance

```
library(shiny)
load("~/Desktop/example.RData")

ui <- fluidPage(title = "Example",
     radioButtons(inputId =  "sex", label = "Sex",
     choiceNames  = list("Male", "Female"), choiceValues = list(0,1)),
     textOutput(outputId = "pred")
     )

server <- function(input, output){
  output$pred <- renderText({
    pred_data <- data.frame(input$sex)
    colnames(pred_data) <- c("sex")
    mdl <- example_mdl
    pred <-predict(example_mdl, newdata = pred_data, type = "response")
    paste("The result is", pred)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please make your code reproducible, e.g. what is your `~/Desktop/example.RData`?

Comment: It is the saved environment that contains the model I want to use in the app. I don't want to create that model in the app because it takes hours to obtain it. So that command is the loading of the example_mdl model that I use in the predict command